# SQL WHERE Clause with CASE

Tags: sql

Trying to setup a SQL stored procedure that if the variable passed to it equals the keyword 'All'  It negates the column 'PlatformName' from the WHERE clause and returns everything in PlatformName and the variable in @Title.

My SQL code is below.

```
WHERE PlatformName = CASE @Platform 
                       WHEN 'All' THEN '' 
                       ELSE @Platform 
                     END 
AND Title LIKE '%' + @Title + '%'
```

The '' is not returning anything.

```
Table
PlatformName   Title
XBox 360       Foobar
PS3            Foobar
```

Comment: This isn't a full question.  Is platform either 'All' or I assume 'XBOX', 'Playstation' etc?  Do a simple select to determine what gets returned when PlatformName = '' and Title LIKE '%' + @Title + '%'.  Tell me what you get.

Comment: See question again.  Sorry for the confusion.  It has been edited.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One way to do exactly what you are trying to do is:

```
WHERE PlatformName = CASE @Platform 
                       WHEN 'All' THEN PlatformName
                       ELSE @Platform 
                     END 
AND Title LIKE '%' + @Title + '%'
```

Another common way you'll see used is:

```
WHERE (PlatformName = @Platform OR @Platform = 'All')
    AND ...
```

I'd recommend testing those for performance.

Answer (score 0):

Just do something like this:

```
WHERE ((PlatformName = @Platform) OR (@Platform = 'All'))
```

Note: if you are doing a join in your query you might see a performance gain if you add this to the join.  For example

```
SELECT * 
FROM Games G
JOIN Platform P ON G.pID = P.pID AND ((PlatformName = @Platform) OR (@Platform = 'All'))
```

This way the scan of the Platform table is reduced and the query will be faster.

Comment: Strange to get a down vote on this correct answer, a comment would be nice.

Comment: I didn't down vote myself but I do doubt your "you can see a big performance" claim.

Comment: @onedaywhen : fair point -- it is dependent on table size of the target table (eg Platform) in this case.  I've seen this change reduce a query from seconds to milliseconds, but it does depend on the tables involved.  I did remove the "big" as a nod to it not always being the case.

Answer (score -1):

The syntax is correct, I tried it on my SQL Server database and it worked with the following query:

```
SELECT * FROM CNT
WHERE CP_NOM = CASE CP_COD WHEN 2824 THEN 'NOMBRE' END AND CP_COD > 10
```

Maybe the error comes with the value of your variables *@Platform* OR *@Title*.

In any case, you can replace the value of your empty platform fields (PlatformName = '') with 'All', you you can make an easier query

```
WHERE PlatformName = @Platform AND Title LIKE '%' + @Title + '%'
```

Comment: This is wrong.  He does not want All to match just the empty fields he wants it to match every record.

Comment: That is what his query is doing. Now with the edited question, I understand what he wants. However, I explained how to use a CASE within WHERE, that is the title of the queston.